# DB2 SQL group row count by time intervals of 10 minutes

Tags: sql, group-by, db2

I have a table in DB2 which contains data such as the following:

| completed_timestamp | details |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-19-15.38.10 | abcd |
| 2021-12-19-15.39.10 | efgh |
| 2021-12-19-15.48.10 | ijkl |
| 2021-12-19-15.49.10 | mnop |
| 2021-12-19-15.54.10 | qrst |

I want to be able to count the number of rows in the table for every 10 minutes e.g.

| Time | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-19-15.40 | 2 |
| 2021-12-19-15.50 | 2 |
| 2021-12-19-16.00 | 1 |

completed_timestamp = Timestamp, details = varchar

I've seen this done in other SQL languages but so far have not figured out how to do it with DB2. How would I do that?

Comment: I would dynamically "10-minute start-end" "table" via recursive CTE and then LEFT JOIN it with the main table.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the minute from the timestamp, divide it by ten, get the next integer, multiply by ten and add it to the hour as minutes :

```
WITH TABLE1 (completed_timestamp, details) AS (
 VALUES 
 (timestamp '2021-12-19-15.38.10', 'abcd'),
 (timestamp '2021-12-19-15.39.10', 'efgh'),
 (timestamp '2021-12-19-15.48.10', 'ijkl'),
 (timestamp '2021-12-19-15.49.10', 'mnop'),
 (timestamp '2021-12-19-15.54.10', 'qrst')
),
trunc_timestamps (time, details) AS (
  SELECT trunc(completed_timestamp, 'HH24') + (ceiling(minute(completed_timestamp) / 10.0) * 10) MINUTES, details FROM table1
)
SELECT trunc_timestamps.time, count(*) FROM trunc_timestamps GROUP BY trunc_timestamps.time
```